# Log4j Filepattern not working when SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy triggered

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

We're having issues with our log4j2 configuration, which we've taken almost directly from https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-rolling-file-appenders section 4.4:

```
<RollingFile name="roll-by-time-and-size"
  fileName="target/log4j2/roll-by-time-and-size/app.log"
  filePattern="target/log4j2/roll-by-time-and-size/app.%d{MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss.SSS}.%i.log.gz"
  ignoreExceptions="false">
    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 KB" />
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="5000000" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="." maxDepth="2">
            <IfFileName glob="target/log4j2/roll-by-time-and-size/app.*.log.gz" />
            <IfLastModified age="20d" />
        </Delete>
    </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>
```

If I reduce the interval to ensure it's rolling based on time, this puts the correct current time in the file name.  But if I increase the interval to 5000 or whatever and let the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy get hit, the timestamp is always the same and the only thing that changes in the index at the end of the file.

This is a problem for us because we have a cron job going and moving rolled-over files to a remote mount point.  This means the next time log4j hits the size based triggering policy, the index will be reset to 1 the timestamp in the filename will be the same even though it shouldn't be (why??), and our cron job will try to move the file but it will be the same filename as another file it already moved.

Using the latest spring boot starter log4j2 (as of now)

Is the a bug or intended behavior.  It doesn't make much sense as an intended behavior, but if so, what should we do to solve this?

Comment: You are saying that with a smaller interval the file timestamp NEVER changes? With your configuration a time based rollover should occur every 5000 seconds at which time the date and time should change.  Also, I would suggest trying with the latest Log4j 2 release. Several fixes were made to these Log4j components that could have fixed this. To use the latest Log4j 2 jars simply remove spring boot starter log4j2 and replace with the log4j dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the policies work as stated in the documentation. I tested it on a Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE app with:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then I used the following dependencies instead of the starter, to make sure I was using the latest versions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In both cases the SizeBased Triggering Policy changes the timestamp in file names only when used **without** the TimeBased Triggering Policy.

From the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SizeBased_Triggering_Policy):

> When combined with a time based triggering policy the file pattern must contain a %i otherwise the target file will be overwritten on every rollover as the SizeBased Triggering Policy will not cause the timestamp value in the file name to change.  When used without a time based triggering policy the SizeBased Triggering Policy will cause the timestamp value to change.

Every time the TimeBasedTriggering Policy triggers a rollover, a file with the new timestamp in its name is created. The next time the SizeBased Triggering Policy is hit, it uses the timestamp from the latest file and changes only the %i part.

As you can't change the way the SizeBasedTriggerin Policy determines the index, **the only obvious solution seems to be changing the cron job to not move the file with the latest timestamp and index**. This should be enough to fix your issue.